# Can we customize our maintenance page?

Tags: feature-request

I guess this is more a question for the moderators or higher-ups in Stack Exchange...

There was some downtime a few minutes ago, so I was directed to [this boring offline page](http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/app_offline.htm). So then I moved on to Server Fault and was hit with [another offline page](http://sstatic.net/serverfault/app_offline.htm) (since it was also down), but that one has some blue screen images on it! **No fair!**

Is it possible for us to customize our maintenance page? I mean, hopefully this page shouldn't be seen very often, but if there is another downtime I'd like to at least have something to look at.

Or maybe even a simple interactive JavaScript (HTML5, if you please) game, like [this](http://www.richardcarter.org/) or [this](http://www.google.com/pacman/) or [this](http://html5games.net/game/classic-bricks/)?

Comment: I like the superuser one. http://sstatic.net/superuser/app_offline.htm

Comment: I like the Pong one, personally.

Comment: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/180/404-page-not-found-image-nominations There was this, but it died out (and that is 404, you're meaning offline)